# PHP Put return value from DB to input box

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

good Day!, i have a question. I have the code below which return the value of pos_name and train_name from my DB. my question is how can i put the returned value inside the textbox in which each textbox has a unique name. cause i will going to save it to another db.

i want something like this

```
 <input type="text" name="<?php echo $row["pos_name"][0] ?>" value="<?php echo $row["train_name"][0] ?>"
 <input type="text" name="<?php echo $row["pos_name"][1] ?>" value="<?php echo $row["train_name"][1] ?>"
// The number of textbox will depend on the number of returned value or the ($i)



//MY PHP CODE =========
<?php 

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con){
        die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("tms",$con);

 $Query="SELECT id,pos_name,train_name FROM pos_train_db ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
 $sql = mysql_query($Query, $con);

            $dyn_table = '<table border="1" cellpadding="10">';
           while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

                $id = $row["id"];
                $pos_name = $row["pos_name"];
                $train_name = $row["train_name"];

                    if ($i % 3 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in this case "3")

            $dyn_table .= '<tr><td>' . $pos_name . '</td>';
        } else {
            $dyn_table .= '<td>' . $pos_name . '</td>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $dyn_table .= '</tr></table>';

            ?>    





       <?php 
//SOME TESTING CODE
               echo $dyn_table;

               echo $i;

               echo "<input type='text' value=" . "$pos_name" . ">";


                ?>
```

Please Help Thank you!

Comment: Is it the `$row["pos_name"]` at the top of your example or the `$pos_name` at the bottom that you are referring to? I mean in terms of which `<input>` you want modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't very clear as to what the OP was asking but -- I suppose this could be part of the answer:

```
<?php 

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con){
        die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("tms",$con);

 $Query="SELECT id,pos_name,train_name FROM pos_train_db ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
 $sql = mysql_query($Query, $con);

            $dyn_table = '<table border="1" cellpadding="10">';
           while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

                $id = html_entity_decode($row["id"]);
                $pos_name = html_entity_decode($row["pos_name"]);
                $train_name = html_entity_decode($row["train_name"]);
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"".$id."\" value=\"".$train_name."\"></input>";

                    if ($i % 3 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in this case "3")

            $dyn_table .= '<tr><td>' . $pos_name . '</td>';
        } else {
            $dyn_table .= '<td>' . $pos_name . '</td>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $dyn_table .= '</tr></table>';

            ?>
```

Comment: Wow thank you! yes this is what i needed    $id = html_entity_decode($row["id"]);
                $pos_name = html_entity_decode($row["pos_name"]);
                $train_name = html_entity_decode($row["train_name"]);
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"".$id."\" value=\"".$train_name."\"></input>";  im new you help me alot! thank you!